# distinct result in Hibernate Query in grails with pagination using association

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have three class interlinked with each other.

Initially I build query without pagination and all search results were fine.
But now I need pagination and don't want to disturb my initial query pattern. Is there any way I could get distinct results.

```
Class Department{
    int id;
    String name;
    static hasMany = [courses:Courses]
}

Class Courses{
    String courseName;
    String courseCode;
    static hasMany = [student:Student]
    static belongsTo = [department:Department]
}

Class Student{
    String studentName;
    String address;
    static belongsTo = [courses:Courses]
}


//controller
def list = Department.createCriteria.listDistinct{
    if(params.id){
         and{eq{"id",params.id}}
    }
    and{
        courses{
            if(params.courseName){
                  and{eq("courseName",params.courseName)}
            }
        }
        and{
            student{
                 if(params.studentName){
                         and{eq("studentName",params.studentName)}
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could not gave you the actual tables and domains, but the relation is pretty much the same as above. It worked really fine for dintinct results but couldnot paginate. I have tried a number of solution but it returns error. I have not recorded any errors till now.
I have came to know listDistinct can not be used for pagination parameters. and list doesnot provide distinct parameters.

I tried projection but couldnot retrieve all the attributes as before. Is there any solutions to it. As I need to search from all possible attributes with all the realtion from any of the three tables. Do I need to switch all my query to another method?

Answer (score 7):

I had a hard time with similar task some time ago - getting criteria, pagination and distinct to work together, and the solutions is:
1. use list() instead of listDistinct()
2. use maxResults and firstResult for pagination
3. use projections { distinct 'id' } for getting distinct results
4. and after getting the list of ids, use getAll() method to retrieve actual objects

so joining it it would be:

```
def ids = Department.createCriteria().list() {
    projections {
        distinct 'id'
    }
    maxResults params.max
    firstResult params.offset

    if(params.id){
         and{eq{"id",params.id}}
    }
    and{
        courses{
            if(params.courseName){
                  and{eq("courseName",params.courseName)}
            }
        }
        and{
            student{
                 if(params.studentName){
                         and{eq("studentName",params.studentName)}
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
return Department.getAll(ids)
```

(code not tested now)

Comment: How do you get totalCount necessary for pagination?

Comment: you have to do another query, or rely on PagedResultSet from hibernate... which does the second query internally ;)

Comment: Been searching for hours for a solution for this exact use case. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that projections { distinct 'id' } limits results in a list of only the IDs being returned. Even listing all of the columns results in the individual column values being returned in a list, rather than getting back a list of the model objects.

Comment: @Schmick that's why there's "return Department.getAll(ids)" in the last line

Comment: Ah nice, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

> The **listDistinct**() method does not work well with the **pagination** options maxResult and firstResult. If you need distinct results with pagination, we currently recommend that you use HQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def search = Department.createCriteria.list(max: max, offset: offset){
//Enter conditions here
}
```

And then:

```
search.unique().totalCount for accessing the total number of results
search.unique() to return back the results.
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I neither liked doing a query first to retrieve full blown list of ids, nor is just a simple listDistinct not enough - because I need the ability to query for *totalCount*.

My strategy is

1. count
2. listDistinct
3. wrap both into a PagedResultWrapper

I came up with a little **GormHelper**:

```
package foo
import grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.TypeConvertingMap

/**
 * Gorm Helper
 *
 * @param < T >
 */
@Log4j
class GormHelper<T> {
    /**
     * Clazz the helper will operate on
     */
    private final Class clazz


    private GormHelper(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz
    }

    /**
     * create a HibernateCriteriaBuilder for the
     * specified clazz
     * @return
     */
    private HibernateCriteriaBuilder createCriteria() {
        return clazz.createCriteria()
    }

    /**
     * List objects by conditions
     * specified in the closure
     * @param params
     * @param closure
     * @return
     */
    List<T> list(Map params, @DelegatesTo(HibernateCriteriaBuilder) Closure closure) {
        createCriteria().list(params, closure)
    }

    /**
     * List all objects
     * @param params
     * @return
     */
    List<T> list(Map params = [:]) {
        return list(params, {})
    }

    /**
     * apply a closure to a HibernateCriteriaBuilder
     * @param crit
     * @param closure
     */
    public static void apply(HibernateCriteriaBuilder crit, Closure closure) {
        if (closure == null) return
        closure.rehydrate(crit, crit, crit).call()
    }

    /**
     * List distinct objects
     * @param _params
     * @param closure
     * @return
     */
    List<T> listDistinct(Map _params, Closure closure) {
        listDistinct(_params, 'id', closure)
    }

    /**
     * List distinct objects
     * @param _params
     * @param distinctProperty
     * @param closure
     * @return
     */
    List<T> listDistinct(Map _params, String distinctProperty, Closure closure) {
        TypeConvertingMap params = new TypeConvertingMap(_params)

        // 1st COUNT
        Integer total = createCriteria().get {
            projections {
                countDistinct(distinctProperty)
            }

            apply(delegate, closure)
        } as Integer

        // 2nd query distinct items with pagination data
        HibernateCriteriaBuilder crit = createCriteria()
        List<T> items = crit.listDistinct {
            apply(delegate, closure)
            setMaxResults(params.int('max'))
            setFirstResult(params.int('offset'))
        }

        // 3rd wrap everything into a PagedResultWrapper
        return PagedResultWrapper.wrap(total, items)
    }

    /**
     * Paged Result Wrapper
     *
     * holds a totalCount beside the data itself
     * can be used as a replacement of the PagedResultList
     */
    public static class PagedResultWrapper extends LinkedList {
        private final Integer total

        /**
         *
         * @param total
         * @param list
         */
        private PagedResultWrapper(Integer total, List list) {
            super()
            this.total = total
            addAll(list)
        }

        /**
         * wrap results and total into a PagedResultWrapper
         * @param total
         * @param collection
         * @return
         */
        public static PagedResultWrapper wrap(Integer total, List collection) {
            return new PagedResultWrapper(total, collection)
        }

        /**
         * get the total count
         * @return
         */
        public int getTotalCount() {
            return total.intValue()
        }
    }

    /**
     * get a Gorm Helper
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    static <V> GormHelper 'for'(Class clazz, Object owner = null) {
        // TODO handle closure ownership
        return new GormHelper<V>(clazz)
    }


}
```

You would use it like so:

```
def usersInSelectedGroups = GormHelper.for(User).listDistinct([max: 10, offset: 20]){
  groups {
    inList('id', [1001, 1002, 1003])
  }
}

println "got ${usersInSelectedGroups.totalCount} users"
usersInSelectedGroups.each {println "\t ${it.username}" }
```

This will **output all users from groups with ids 1001, 1002, 1003** - if a user is member of several of those groups, **they will be only listed once in the result list** ...