# How to get distinct results using Grails GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have one to many relationship between two objects. Like Order and Items

```
class Order {
   static hasMany = [items: ItemModel]
   ...//some properties
}

class ItemModel {
   // some properties
}

  class SearchController {
   def doSearch() {
      def criteriaOrder = Order.createCriteria();
      def order =  criteriaOrder.list(params) {
         and {
            items {
               like("partNumber", itemName)
            }
            or {
               if (customerName){
                  like('bclientName', customerName)
                  like('dclientName',customerName)
               }
            }
            if (fromDate && toDate) {
               between('orderDate', fromDate,toDate)
            }
         }
      }
     }
   }
```

When I am going to search it gives duplicate result. I used unique() on list object the it gives unqiue but pagination is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019873/distinct-result-in-hibernate-query-in-grails-with-pagination-using-association

Answer (score 2):

add [distinct projection](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) to your query:

distinct-based solution:

```
def order =  criteriaOrder.list(params) {
     projections{ 
       distinct 'id'
       property 'bclientName'
       property 'dclientName'
       property 'orderDate'
       // add further props you need to show in the list
     }
     and {
        items {
           like("partNumber", itemName)
        }
  ....
}.collect{ 
  Order o = new Order( bclientName:it[ 1 ], dclientName:it[ 2 ], orderDate:it[ 3 ] ) 
  o.id = it[ 0 ]
  o
}
```

groupBy-based solution:

```
def order =  criteriaOrder.list(params) {
     projections{ 
       groupProperty 'id'
       max 'orderDate'
     }
     and {
        items {
           like("partNumber", itemName)
        }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes it is giving id in results but i want to get Order Object

Comment: do you need complete objects to be rendered as a list, or only a couple of fields?

Comment: complete list of order object

Comment: according to projections it gives all id but i need objects

Comment: still i am getting only order's object ids but i need complete object

Comment: first one whe i showing on gsp page  [Ljava.lang.Object;@fc686aa [Ljava.lang.Object;@896820c [Ljava.lang.Object;@26505523 [Ljava.lang.Object;@25363e8a [Ljava.lang.Object;@3e7d338e [Ljava.lang.Object;@3277f138 [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b043ba3 [Ljava.lang.Object;@3ab9eee4 [Ljava.lang.Object;@637b1466 [Ljava.lang.Object;@3d73228

Comment: This is i am getting. i want to show properties of the object

Comment: is it affect on performance bcz every time new Object is going to create.